# M2EPro admin pages are blank

Tags: magento-1.8, m2e-pro

M2EPro seems to not be working.  When I click on "sell on ebay" in the admin, it just refreshes the admin dashboard.  When I got to system->configuration->M2EPro, all links end up with a blank area.

Any Idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your license got **EXPIRED**.. Renewal it. I know you are thinking it is free. But you need to **renewal** it. Contact extension's support guys.

Comment: The license is only 3 months old.  Should not be expired.  Also, how do I enter a new license key if I can't see any of the M2EPro pages?

Comment: Is this extension is on your local server or is on the live server?

Comment: It's on the live server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that it was disabled in System->Configuration->Advanced->Disable Modules Output.  It was set to "disable" and all I had to do was enable it.